# Quaternion rotation by phi and theta instead of xyz in gl-matrix

Tags: javascript, 3d, quaternions, gl-matrix

[gl-matrix](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix)'s [quaternion object](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/blob/master/src/gl-matrix/quat.js#L245) has 3 functions `rotateX`, `rotateY` and `rotateZ` which rotates quaternion by the specific axis.
Now I want to do the same using phi and theta instead of xyz.

How is this possible ? Is it possible to extract some value then pass it to `rotateX`, `rotateY` and `rotateZ` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve exactly but in your `quat` object you have a function `setAxisAngle` that allows you to pass any axis and amount of rotation around that axis. This way you can have a quaternion rotated around arbitrary vector.

If you need few such rotations at once, just multiply few quaternions (but remember to normalise them!).